# Who gave Scotty the nickname "Scotty"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-reboot

On screen, the first time we hear the nickname "Scotty" for Montgomery Scott is in the episode ["The Naked Time"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/7.htm):

> **KIRK:** I'll hold you to that half second, *Scotty*.

The reboot films go out of their way to create a foundational conversation where the nickname "Bones" for McCoy is used for what is clearly the *first* time; however, they give no such treatment to "Scotty".  The nickname comes up all of a sudden in the 2009 film, several scenes after meeting Scott:

> **KIRK:** How are we, *Scotty*?
>
> **SCOTT:** Unbelievably, sir, the ship is in position.

To be clear, I'm not wondering *why* he has this nickname — it's clearly an affectionate reference to his family name and heritage.  I'm wondering *who* gave it to him.  Was it Kirk?  Was it someone else in the crew, like McCoy?  Or was it a nickname he was already fond of, and then encouraged Kirk and others to use?

The [Memory Alpha article on Scotty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Montgomery_Scott) simply says that he is "referred to as Scotty by his shipmates".

The [official StarTrek.com database entry on him](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/scott) only says that he is "known as 'Scotty' as well as 'the miracle worker' to his longtime comrades James T. Kirk and crew".

**Who gave Scotty his nickname?**

Comment: Who gave an Engineer with the name Scott (who's Scottish) the nickname Scotty? Every single person he's ever met.

Comment: @Valorum : Just don't call him Shirley!  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis Shirley, you jest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## James Doohan

According to Scotty's [Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scotty#Background_information), it was James Doohan's idea to name the character Scotty:

(see 3:26 in the above video)

<sub>This is a bit of a tongue-in-cheek answer; I know that the OP is looking for an in-universe answer, but I thought I'dd add in this detail</sub>

Comment: Despite the fact that I was seeking an in-universe answer, I like this a lot, so +1.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis I just thought it was important to add in this detail!  Great question!

Answer (score 10):

In the reboot universe, the [tie-in novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel)) for Star Trek suggests that *Kirk* was the first on the Enterprise to employ this particular nickname. That being said, Mr Scott has almost certainly heard it before, what with being Scottish and called Scott.

> The engineer considered. Then he broke out in a wide, wild grin. “At
>   the hearin’ about the dog they said that unless I straightened up I
>   was going to the dogs. Aye, Mister Pointy-ear, let’s do it! What’s the
>   worst that can happen? That I spread meself all over a wide corner of
>   the cosmos? Better to go out in a flash than a footnote.” He looked
>   over at the younger officer. “And you, Lieutenant—Kirk, was it?”
>
> **Kirk nodded. “I don’t have any choice, Mister Scott—Scotty.” The
>   engineer didn’t chastise him for employing the nickname**. “There’s far
>   more at stake here than you yet realize. And I can’t do anything about
>   it if I’m stuck here on this planet.” He smiled thinly. “No matter how
>   convivial the company or engaging the surroundings.”

Comment: I like to imagine Prime Spock let Kelvin Kirk know of the nickname, creating something of a bootstrap paradox in that timeline.